# Only image text is showing from firebase in recyclerview fragment Image is not loading

Tags: javascript, android, html

My images from firebase are not showing in image view but the name of an image is showing in the above text view of the recycler view. Here is my code please help.
FragmentActivity

```js
package com.example.bbeast.HomeActivity;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.bbeast.R;
import com.example.bbeast.Upload;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class fragmentHealthTips extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private DatabaseReference mDataRef;
    private Uri mImageuri;





    View view;

    public void fragmentHealthTips() {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.healthtips_fragment, container, false);
        mRecyclerView =(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.healthtips_recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mDataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Uploads");
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<HealthTips>()
                .setQuery(mDataRef, HealthTips.class)
                .build();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<HealthTips, hViewHolder> adapter= new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<HealthTips, hViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final hViewHolder holder, int i, @NonNull final HealthTips healthTips) {
//directly get the values like this
                String Iname = healthTips.getName();
                String Uimage = healthTips.getImage();
                holder.hName.setText(Iname);
                Picasso.get()
                        .load(Uimage)
                        .into(holder.hImageview);

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public hViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items_healthtips, parent, false);
                hViewHolder viewHolder = new hViewHolder(view);
                return viewHolder;
            }
        };
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();

    }
    public static class hViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView hName;
        ImageView hImageview;

        public hViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            hName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.healthtips_name);
            hImageview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.healthtips_imageView);

        }
    }

}
```

Xml file of items.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/healthtips_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/healthtips_imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/imageview_bg"/>


    </LinearLayout>



</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Model class, Healthtips activity.

```js
package com.example.bbeast.HomeActivity;

import java.util.jar.Attributes;

public class HealthTips {
    public String name, image;

    public HealthTips(){


    }
    public HealthTips(String name, String image){
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;

    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getImage(){
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(String image){
        this.image= image;
    }


}
```

Gradle dependencies.

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bbeast"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/Admin Activity', 'src/main/java/com.example.bbeast/ui.main/Admin Activity']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT'


}
```

Please help me in getting an image in the image view. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check
 of the UImage is a valid path, normally I would do something like this..

P.S Not a RecyclerView but you get the idea

```
    imageview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);

    _path_child_listener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot _param1, String _param2) {
            GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>> _ind = new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>>() {};
            final String _childKey = _param1.getKey();
            final HashMap<String, Object> _childValue = _param1.getValue(_ind);
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Uri.parse(_childValue.get("imageUrl").toString())).into(imageview1);
            //imageUrl is pushed to Firebase Storage onUploadCompleted
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot _param1, String _param2) {
            GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>> _ind = new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>>() {};
            final String _childKey = _param1.getKey();
            final HashMap<String, Object> _childValue = _param1.getValue(_ind);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot _param1, String _param2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot _param1) {
            GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>> _ind = new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>>() {};
            final String _childKey = _param1.getKey();
            final HashMap<String, Object> _childValue = _param1.getValue(_ind);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError _param1) {
            final int _errorCode = _param1.getCode();
            final String _errorMessage = _param1.getMessage();

        }
    };
    path.addChildEventListener(_path_child_listener);
}
private void initializeLogic() {
}
```